# Let a and b be integers. If a+b ≥ 99, then a ≥ 50 or b ≥ 50.

Tags: inequality

How would I prove this?

I thought maybe a contrapositive may work but not sure how I can prove it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Contrapositive works.  Try it.  Not ($a \ge 50$ or $b \ge 50$) means...

Comment: So since a < 50 and b < 50 I can assume a ≤ 49 and b ≤ 49 since they are integers?

Comment: Yes, that works for me!  We would be in trouble if the claim were more than about integers.  Please make your Question's body self-contained, so that Readers don't have to rely on the title for statement of a problem.

Comment: Will do, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

A proof by contradition works. If neither $a$ and $b$ are greater or equal to $50$ , then this implies that $a \le 49$ and $b \le 49$ since $a$ and $b$ are integers.

This implies that $a+b \le 98$. However, $a+b \ge 99$. Contradiction.

Comment: Or, end with "$a + b \le 98$" and declare "Contraposition."

Comment: So since a < 50 and b < 50 I can assume a ≤ 49 and b ≤ 49 since they are integers?

Comment: @MichaelLoffredo Yes.